# How to find closest values between 2 arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

for example:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2,3.1,3.2]
print answer
>>[1.1,2.1,3.1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Provide more details for other scenario like, Instead of 2.1 we have 2.6 and don't have any other values between 2-3 ??

Comment: Hi, you haven't defined "_closest_". Perhaps you're referring to the absolute value from? What happens if `b = [0.9, 1.1, 1.9, 2.1, 2.9, 3.1]`? Please read through [ask] and [this question checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist) on how your question could be clearer. Thanks.

Comment: There is not 0.9 and 1.1 for 1 in my case. My original numbers are too spesific.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example lists this is my solution.
It uses list comprehension to list the differences between a and the values in b. This uses abs(value) to only have the positive value of the difference.
It indexes the smallest value in difference and finds the value in b. This gets added to answer and printed in the end.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2]
answer = []
for i in a:
    difference = [abs(i - j) for j in b]
    answer.append(b[difference.index(min(difference))])
print(answer)
```

This solution works - of course - best with integers and with unique values in list b. It shouldn't matter for a since you would just have the same value twice in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function find_closest takes in one value from the list `a` and the whole list `b` and returns the value in the list that is closest.

We build the answer by appending the result of the function for each entry in the `a` list.

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2,3.1,3.2]


def find_closest(anchor, comparisons):
    # find index of number in comparisons that is closest to anchor
    diffs = [abs(anchor-val) for val in comparisons]
    minimum_index = diffs.index(min(diffs))
    return comparisons[minimum_index]
answer = []
for comp in a:
    answer.append(find_closest(comp,b))

print(answer)
```